# Remove all elements of an associative array if they have the a specific word in the key

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I would like to remove all elements of an associative array if the key has a substring of 'TB1' in the key.

My array looks like:

```
$output= [
       'TB1_course' => 'required'
       'TB1_session' => 'required'
       'TB2_course' => 'required'
    ]
```

I would like to remove TB1_course and TB1_session, so that my final array looks like:

```
$output =[
   'TB2_course' => 'required
]
```

Is there any way to go about doing this in an easy concise fashion?

My initial guess was to use a for each loop:

```
foreach ($output as $key =>$value){
//remove
}
```

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: is this ok `unset($output['TB1_course']); unset($output['TB1_session']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the array by key:

```
$input = [
    'TB1_course' => 'required',
    'TB1_session' => 'required',
    'TB2_course' => 'required',
];

$filter = function ($key) {
    return substr($key, 0, 4) === 'TB2_';
};

$output = array_filter($input, $filter, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

var_dump($output);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  'TB2_course' =>
  string(8) "required"
}
```

See http://php.net/array_filter for the documentation of the `array_filter` function that is useful to filter arrays.

Comment: It works perfectly, Thank you!